# How to use adjust space between individual rows of a figure without applying it to all rows

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to create a figure using matplotlib that contains 12 plots in total.
The plots are distributed as follows: There are 3 columns, and 4 rows. I want the first two rows to be "sticking" together along the y axis/vertically, i.e. there shall be no axis labels, and no figure title of the lower row in between them. The same goes for rows 3 and 4. However, I want some space between the two "row-groups" So basically rows 1 and 2 stick together, and row 3 and 4 stick together, but some space between row 2 and 3.

I was only able to find parameters that influence *all* heigh space between subplots, but none that let me modify the height space individually. In this MWE, I'm using the `"figure.subplot.hspace"` `rcParam` to modify the hspace.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

params = {
    "xtick.labelsize": 12,
    "ytick.labelsize": 12,
    "xtick.direction": "in",
    "ytick.direction": "in",
    "xtick.top": True,
    "ytick.right": True,
    "figure.subplot.left": 0.045,
    "figure.subplot.right": 0.99,
    "figure.subplot.bottom": 0.05,
    "figure.subplot.top": 0.93,
    "figure.subplot.wspace": 0.15,
    "figure.subplot.hspace": 0.0,
}
mpl.rcParams.update(params)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # invent some data
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    y_main = np.sin(x)
    y_diff = 1. - y_main


    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 22))
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(4,3,1,)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(4,3,2,)
    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(4,3,3,)
    ax1_sub = fig.add_subplot(4,3,4)
    ax2_sub = fig.add_subplot(4,3,5)
    ax3_sub = fig.add_subplot(4,3,6)
    ax4 = fig.add_subplot(4,3,7,)
    ax5 = fig.add_subplot(4,3,8,)
    ax6 = fig.add_subplot(4,3,9,)
    ax4_sub = fig.add_subplot(4,3,10)
    ax5_sub = fig.add_subplot(4,3,11)
    ax6_sub = fig.add_subplot(4,3,12)


    subaxes = [ax1_sub, ax2_sub, ax3_sub, ax4_sub, ax5_sub, ax6_sub]
    mainaxes = [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6]

    for ax in mainaxes:
        ax.set_title("Title")
        ax.plot(x, y_main)
        ax.set_ylabel("y(x)")
        ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False)

    for ax in subaxes:
        ax.plot(x, y_diff)
        ax.set_xlabel("xlabel")
        ax.set_ylabel("1 - y(x)")


    #  plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig("mwe.png", dpi=200)
    plt.close()
```

The resulting figure is as follows:

[image]

This is exactly how I want rows 1&2 and 3&4 to "stick together". But as you can see, the axis labels and figure titles are now missing and inside other figures, respectively.

How can I add some space between two specific rows only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such 'special' plot arrangements I like to use [`gridspec`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html).
(see also [Using Gridspec to make multi-column/row subplot layouts](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_multicolumn.html)).

It includes [`subgridspec`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.SubplotSpec.html?highlight=subgridspec#matplotlib.gridspec.SubplotSpec.subgridspec), and by using both together you can individually set the `hspace` as intended.
[image]

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

params = {
    "xtick.labelsize": 12,
    "ytick.labelsize": 12,
    "xtick.direction": "in",
    "ytick.direction": "in",
    "xtick.top": True,
    "ytick.right": True,
    "figure.subplot.left": 0.045,
    "figure.subplot.right": 0.99,
    "figure.subplot.bottom": 0.05,
    "figure.subplot.top": 0.93,
    "figure.subplot.wspace": 0.15,
    # "figure.subplot.hspace": 0.0,  # done within gridspec
}
mpl.rcParams.update(params)

# invent some data
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y_main = np.sin(x)
y_diff = 1. - y_main

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 22), facecolor=(1, 1, 1))
    
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 1, hspace=0.15)  # spacing between the two groups
# print(gs)
    
gs0 = gs[0].subgridspec(2, 3, hspace=0, wspace=0.2)  # spacing within the groups
gs1 = gs[1].subgridspec(2, 3, hspace=0, wspace=0.2)
# print(gs0)

set1, set1_sub = gs0.subplots()
# print(set1)
set1[0].text(0.5, 0.5, "set1[0]")
set1[1].text(0.5, 0.5, "set1[1]")
set1[2].text(0.5, 0.5, "set1[2]")
set1_sub[0].text(0.5, 0.5, "set1_sub[0]")
set1_sub[1].text(0.5, 0.5, "set1_sub[1]")
set1_sub[2].text(0.5, 0.5, "set1_sub[2]")
    
set2 = gs1.subplots()
# print(set2)
set2[0,0].text(0.5, 0.5, "set2[0]")
set2[0,1].text(0.5, 0.5, "set2[1]")
set2[0,2].text(0.5, 0.5, "set2[2]")
set2[1,0].text(0.5, 0.5, "set2_sub[0]")
set2[1,1].text(0.5, 0.5, "set2_sub[1]")
set2[1,2].text(0.5, 0.5, "set2_sub[2]")

mainaxes = [set1[0], set1[1], set1[2], set2[0,0], set2[0,1], set2[0,2]]
subaxes = [set1_sub[0], set1_sub[1], set1_sub[2], set2[1,0], set2[1,1], set2[1,2]]

for ax in mainaxes:
    ax.set_title("Title")
    ax.plot(x, y_main)
    ax.set_ylabel("y(x)")
    ax.tick_params(labelbottom=False)

for ax in subaxes:
    ax.plot(x, y_diff)
    ax.set_xlabel("xlabel")
    ax.set_ylabel("1 - y(x)")

#plt.savefig("mwe.png", dpi=200)
plt.show()
```

Notes:

- The `.text` are included as a help to identify the positions, just remove them when you've got the overview.
- set1/2 (groups) are build slightly different to show how gridspec works

  - both ways have the same result
  - activate the `# print` statements for further insight
- `fig.add_gridspec(2, 1)` 'main' grid with 2 rows and 1 column
- `gs[0].subgridspec(2, 3)` subgrid within the 1st main row, with 2 rows and 3 columns